# How to implement tapestry simulator in php

Tags: php, image, simulation

I want to implement a simulator like the one shown on this page http://www.fama.es/bolero.html#direct-simulator-0. I want to use ImageMagick with PHP. I have no experience with image manipulation in PHP. Any ideas

Comment: It is not easy and there are some posts about shirts on the Imagemagick form that should get you started: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=23348&hilit=shirt

Comment: Thanks, it's a good point to start. I will read more about topic

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have each part of the sofa as a masked image. Then make new versions with the gray changed to whatever color you want (via Imagemagick command such as +level-colors, or -fill newcolor -opaque oldcolor). Then you need to your PHP to control which color image is displayed in the viewer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the case of applying a texture to the masked image, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I test this code `convert sleeves.png pattern.png \
\( -clone 0 -auto-level \) \
\( -clone 1 -clone 0 -alpha set -virtual-pixel transparent -compose displace \
-set option:compose:args -5x-5 -composite \) \
-delete 0,1 -compose multiply -composite sleeves_pattern.png` in console and work very well. Soo, how I do this in PHP?